# How to always use a specific DB connection for certain django model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-database, multi-database

I will add a procedure to a django app where I need to store data but only for a few hours, also I don't wat to add another table to my db schema (which is kind of big), I'm thinking to use redis for the task, in the end what I want to achieve is to have a `Transfer` model, and I want this model always be using another database for its CRUD operations.

Example:

```
Transfer.objects.all()  # Always be the same as Transfer.objects.using('redis').all()
OtherModel.objects.all()  # Always use default DB

# Same for save
transfer_instance.save()  # Always translate to transfer_instance.save(using='redis')
other_instance.save()  # Work as usuall using default DB
```

How can I achieve this? I don't mind using obscure trickery as long as it works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a Database Router to achieve what you need.

Here is the official documentation for [Using Database Routers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers)